# Find entries with (certain) multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I have this query:

```
books = Book.includes(:tags).where(tags:{ id: [1, 2] })
```

The result contains all books having tags **1 OR 2**. How can I change this to get only books which have *both* tags (**1 AND 2**)?

My approach was:

```
books = Book.includes(:tags).where(tags:{ id: 1 }).where(tags:{ id: 2 })
```

This went wrong, because the the second where overwrites the first one.

Comment: `Book.includes(:tags).where(tags:{ id: [1, 2] }).to_sql` will tell you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that this query searches for *any* the ids, but I would like to have a way to get books with *both* tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
books = Book.includes(:tags).where("tags:{ id: ? } AND tags:{ id: ?}", 1, 2)
```

Comment: i think it's `Book.includes(:tags).where("tags.id = ? AND tags.id ?", 1, 2)` but yeah

Comment: well, actually, that does not work either because of the join... so i guess you would have to make 2 joins with `tags1.id = x AND tags2.id = y`